# Using Sublime Text 2 with Portable Python

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I have portable python and portable sublime text installed on a flash drive. I edited the python-build file so that it would use portable python to run the programs but it doesn't print anything into the sublime text window, it just opens up a command prompt window which immediately closes if the program stops or has an error. Is there anyway to make the output pop up in sublime text? Ideally, I would like to make this usable on all windows computers so I can keep my workflow portable!

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like path to your custom Python interpreter is not correct or similar misconfiguration issue. Can you clarify details and show your build files and other stuff in the question.

Comment: I figured it out. I changed my path to portablepython/Apps/python.exe. This fixed it. But now I have a new question. My build breaks if the flashdrive drive letter changes from computer to computer. Here is my python build file. http://pastebin.com/teiUjcHs

Comment: Hmmm... I think there is no way to have solution around changing flash drive letter easily. Either you need to create a script which modifies the config file and run it for each computer when you enter the drive. Or just manually edit every time you go to a computer.

Comment: Can you make something run whenever you plug the flashdrive in?

Comment: Not from the flash drive, but if you are plugging it always into the same computer then yes. Maybe you can add a .BAT script in flash driver root which you click every time you plug it into a computer and it will run scripts necessary to fix your project files.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and after a bit of troubleshooting, here is my solution:

1) Use the build system:

```
{
"cmd": ["\\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\\App\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"}
```

This build will open your program in Python Portable.
Instead of specifying your flash drive letter, using "\" will go to the path relative to the root of the current drive.

2) At the end of your code add the following line to prevent force closing:

```
os.system("pause")
```

Also, don't forget to import the "os" module:

```
import os
```